# How to vertically align text in my columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a footer to my HTML page and I want the texts to appear directly beneath the headings:

[image]

As can be seen this works when there are 4 rows but if I write only one row it doesn't come on top. I tried putting `valign="top"` but it didn't work:

```
          <div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-area">
         <table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2' border='0' width='798'><tbody><tr><td><h3>Contact</h3></td><td><h3>Opportunity</h3></td><td width='100'><h3>Products&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</h3></td><td><h3>Policies</h3></td><td><h3>Our Sites</h3></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Bnano International Ltd<br>

207 Regent Street<br>
London, England<br>info@bnano.eu
</td><td><a href="/">How to join</a><br>
<a href="/">Why join Bnano</a><br>
<a href="/">Financial opportunity</a><br>
<a href="/">Distributors resources</a> <td valign="top"><a href="/">Water</a>



</td><td valign="top"><a href="/">Company Policies</a><br>
<a href="/">Retail term of use</a><br>
<a href="/">Privacy policy</a><br>
<a href="/">Return policy</a></td><td valign="top"><a href="/">Scandinavia</a><br>
<a href="/">Discover Bnano</a></td></tr></tbody></table>



    </div>
  </div><!-- footer -->
```

My CSS file is

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption, hr, button {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align: baseline; background:none;}
table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {padding:4px;vertical-align:middle;}
ol, ul {list-style:none;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, li {line-height:100%;}
blockquote, q {quotes:none;}
q:before,
q:after {content: '';}
table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
input, textarea, select{
    font:11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
form, fieldset{border-style:none;}
html {height:100%;}
body {
    min-width:1004px;
    color:#404344;
    height:100%;
    font:13px/16px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    background:#fff;
    margin: 0 1px 1px;
}
img{border-style:none;}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
}
a:focus {outline:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
/* wrapper */
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
* html #wrapper {height:100%;}
/* header */
#header {
    width:100%;
    background:#1596c3 url(/welcome/static/images/bg-header.png) repeat-x;
}
#header:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:"";
}
/* header-area */
.header-area {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:948px;
    padding:0 23px;
}
/* top-panel*/
.top-panel {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:36px;
    padding:6px 0 0 4px;
    margin:0 0 19px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999999 !important;
}
/* search-form */
.search-form {
    float:right;
    margin:0 10px 0 15px;
}
.search-form form {float:left;}
.top-panel .text {
    float:left;
    padding:6px 13px 7px 13px;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/images/bg-text.gif) no-repeat;
}
.top-panel .text input {
    font:13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color:#8cc0d3;
    float:left;
    width:157px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 -2px 0 0;
    border:0;
    background:none;
}
.top-panel .text input:focus {outline:none;}
.search-form .search {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/images/btn-search.gif) no-repeat;
    width:26px;
    height:27px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    line-height:0;
    font-size:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:0;
}
/* email-form */
.email-form {
    float:left;
    width:214px;
}
.email-form form {float:left;}
.email-form .go {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/btn-go.gif) no-repeat;
    width:26px;
    height:27px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    line-height:0;
    font-size:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:0;
}
/* links */
.top-panel .links {
    float:right;
    padding:9px 0 0;
    width:400px;
}
.top-panel .links .title {
    float:left;
    color:#fdfdfd;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top:1px;
}
.top-panel .links .title .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
.top-panel .links ul {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:-5px 0 0;
}
.top-panel .links li {
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 0 9px;
}
.top-panel .links li img {display:block;}
/* header-info */
.header-info {
    padding:0 0 95px 17px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99999 !important;
}
/* logo */
.logo {
    float:left;
    background:url(/welcome/static/images/bnano_logo.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:220px;
    height:76px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    margin:0 0 0 -15px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
.logo a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
/* nav */
#nav {
    float:right;
    padding:20px 0 0;
}
#nav li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 3px 0 3px;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:17px;
}
#nav li a {
    float:left;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
    color:#a9cfdd;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav li a span {
    float:left;
    padding:5px 6px 4px 11px;
}
#nav li.active a,
#nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#f6f6f6;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/btn-active.gif) no-repeat 100% -23px;
}
#nav li.active a span,
#nav li a:hover span {
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/btn-active.gif) no-repeat;
}
#nav li a .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
/* info-area */
#header .info-area {
    height:398px;
    width:900px;
    background:none !important;
    padding:15px 2px 0 13px;
    margin-top:-148px;
    margin-left:25px;
}

#header .info-area .txt {
    float:left;
    color:#f6f8f9;
    font-size:19px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
#header .info-area .txt .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#header .info-area .txt .text .cufon {margin-top:1px !important;}
#header .info-area .title {
    color:#a9cfdd;
    font-size:48px;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:51px;
    padding-top:55px;
    width:550px;
}
#header .info-area .title span {
    font-size:35px;
    line-height:36px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:32px !important;
    padding-top:1px;
}
#header .info-area .title em {
    font-style:normal;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:53px !important;
}
#header .info-area .desc {
    font-family: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    line-height:20px;
    margin: 8px 0 25px 3px;
    font-size:19px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999 !important;
    padding-top:130px;
    width:550px;
}
#header .info-area .txt .text {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    padding:0 0 5px;
}
#header .info-area .txt .text1 {
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/ico03.gif) no-repeat 2px 9px;
    padding:26px 0 27px 114px;
}
#header .info-area .img {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:500px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
#header .info-area .more {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:25px;
    letter-spacing:1px !important;
    margin-top:23px;
    margin-left:-3px;
}
#header .info-area .more a {
    color:#f6f8f9;
    float:left;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bullet05.gif) no-repeat 5px 3px;
    padding:0 0 0 19px;
    font-size:18px;
}
#header .info-area .more a span {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
#header .info-area .more a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
#header .info-area .more a:hover span {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f6f8f9;
    padding:0;
}
/* main */
#main {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:58px 0 122px;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bg-main-area.gif) repeat-x;
}
/* onecolumn */
#onecolumn {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1004px;
    position:relative;
}
#onecolumn ul {
    margin:10px 0 10px 25px;
}
#onecolumn li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 12px 15px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bullet03.gif) no-repeat 2px 6px;
}
#onecolumn  h2 {
    color:#062f3d;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 8px 0;

}
#onecolumn  h2 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#onecolumn  h2 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#onecolumn  h2 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#onecolumn  h3 {
    color:#676a6b;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
#onecolumn  h3 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#onecolumn  h3 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:-3px 0 0;
}
#onecolumn  h3 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#onecolumn .content {
    padding:0 48px 10px 48px;
}
#onecolumn content p {margin:0 0 16px;}
/* twocolumns */
#twocolumns {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1004px;
    position:relative;
}
#twocolumns h2 {
    color:#062f3d;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 14px 0;
}
#twocolumns h2 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#twocolumns h2 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:-3px 0 0;
    font-size:30px;
}
#twocolumns h2 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#twocolumns h3 {
    color:#062f3d;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
#twocolumns h3 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#twocolumns h3 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:-3px 0 0;
    font-size:26px;
}
#twocolumns h3 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#twocolumns h4 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 10px 0 17px 2px;
}
/* content */
#content {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:596px;
    padding:0 20px 10px 48px;
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
#content p {
    margin:0 2px 16px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}
#content p img {
    padding:10px;
}
#content .more {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    padding:0 0 16px 4px;
    font-size:14px;
}
#content .more a {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bullet01.gif) no-repeat 0 55%;
    padding:0 0 0 13px;
    color:#404344;
}
#content .more a:hover {
    color:#138db7;
}
/* video-block */
#content .video-block {
    width:616px;
    margin:0 -20px 0 -19px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 4px 0 15px;
    background:#d4dadb url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bg-video-block.gif) repeat-x;
}
#content .video-block:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:"";
}
#content .video-block .heading {
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bg-heading.gif) no-repeat;
    width:176px;
    height:51px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 0 4px -7px;
    padding:25px 0 0 15px;
}
#content .video-block .info-col {
    float:left;
    width:271px;
    padding:0 0 0 7px;
    margin:-6px 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
#content .video-block h3 {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:3px 0 0;
    margin:0;
}
#twocolumns .video-block strong {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
}
#twocolumns .video-block span{
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#fff;
}
/* list */
#content .video-block .list {height:1%;}
#content .video-block .list li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 13px 13px;
    line-height:14px;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bullet02.gif) no-repeat 1px 4px;
}
#content .video-block .list li h4 {
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#967723;
}
#content .video-block .list li h4 a {color:#967723;}
#content .video-block .list li p {margin:0;}
#content .video-block .video {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 -8px;
    padding:30px 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
#content .video-block .video img {display:block;}
#content blockquote {
  font: 14px/22px normal helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
}
#content blockquote p {margin:0;}
#content blockquote cite {font-style:normal;}
/* blocks */
#content .blocks {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:582px;
}
#content .blocks h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#4499b7;
    margin:0 0 13px;
}
#content .block-holder {
    width:590px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 -8px 5px 0;
}
#content .blocks .block {
    width:290px;
    margin:0 4px 0 0;
    padding:18px 0 10px;
    float:left;
    color:#ba9d50;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:13px;
    background:#dcddde;
}
#content .blocks .block .img {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0 18px;
}
#content .blocks .block .img img {vertical-align:top;}
#content .blocks .block p {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
}
#content .blocks .block p a {color:#ba9d50;}
#content ul {
    margin:10px 0 10px 25px;
}
#content li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 12px 15px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bullet03.gif) no-repeat 2px 6px;
}
/* sidebar */
#sidebar {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width:315px;
    padding:0 3px 0 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
#sidebar p {
    margin-left:2px;
}
/* news-list */
#sidebar .news-list {
    width:300px;
    padding:0 15px 19px 0;
}
#sidebar .news-list li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 12px 15px;
    line-height:14px;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bullet03.gif) no-repeat 2px 6px;
}
#sidebar .news-list li h4 {
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 1px;
}
/* news-list1 */
#sidebar .news-list1 {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    width:300px;
}
#sidebar .news-list1 li {
    background-position:3px 6px;
    padding-left:17px;
}
#sidebar .news-list1 h4 {
    color:#967723;
    position:relative;
    word-spacing:-1px;
}
#sidebar .news-list1 h4 a {color:#967723;}
/* #sidebar .news-list1 h4 a {color:#967723;} */
/* info-list */
#sidebar .info-list {
    width:269px;
    padding:1px 0 0;
}
#sidebar .info-list li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:27px;
    margin:0 0 2px;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bg-info-list.gif) no-repeat;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a {
    float:left;
    padding:9px 10px 4px 41px;
    color:#138db7;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bullet04.gif) no-repeat 13px 50%;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
#sidebar .info-list li a span {
    float:left;
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a strong {float:left;}
#sidebar .view {
    display:block;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/assets/files/img/btn/online-store.png) no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:30px;
    width:191px;
    height:75px;
    margin:0 0 0 -8px;
    padding:22px 115px 0 18px;
}
#sidebar .view span {
    font-size:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
#sidebar .view strong {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
#sidebar .view .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#sidebar .view:hover {text-decoration:none;}
/* footer */
#footer {
    height:206px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:-106px 0 0;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:14px;
    color:#9ddbf1;
    background:#1494c1 url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bg-footer.gif) repeat-x;
}
/* footer-area */
.footer-area {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:948px;
    padding:52px 1px 0;
}
.footer-area p a {color:#000000;}
#footer .copyright {
    float:left;
    width:390px;
    margin:5px 30px 0 0;
}
#footer .copyright p {text-align:right;}
#footer .logo1 {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/logo01.png) no-repeat;
    width:130px;
    height:102px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    position:relative;
    margin:-52px 30px 0 0;
}
#footer .logo1 a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
/* info */
#footer .info {
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    position:relative;
    margin:-9px 0 0;
}
#sidebar form { 
width : 295px;
height : auto; 
text-align : left; 
margin-top : 10px;
margin-bottom:25px;
border: none;
}

#sidebar input { 
width : 240px; 
height:20px;
background : url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/bg-input.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color : #666; 
font-size : 14px; 
margin-bottom : 6px; 
padding : 10px 10px 8px 10px;
border:0;
}

#sidebar textarea { 
width : 265px; 
height : 105px;
background : url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/textarea-b.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 0%; 
padding : 10px 30px 10px 10px; 
font-size : 14px; 
color : #666; 
margin-bottom : 1px;
border:0;
}

#sidebar .button { 
background : url(http://www.supernaturalsilver.com/img/button.png) no-repeat 0% 0%; 
width : 104px; 
height : 30px; 
color : #fff; 
font-size : 13px; 
cursor:pointer;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:180px;
padding : 5px 0 5px 0;
border:0;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

#sidebar .invalidValue { 
color:#c21313;
}
```

Can you tell me how to achieve that the texts "Water" and "Scandinavia" appear on top in their columns?

Comment: A live demo is much more useful. I can't really render HTML and CSS in my head...

Comment: Put three lines with `<br>&nbsp;` after `Water` and two after `Discover Bnano` in the respective `<td>` entries.

Comment: @Blender: next you'll be telling us you can't read hex dumps either?  :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS you have specifically set your `vertical-align` to middle, which may be overriding the `valign` attribute. Take a look at this rule:

```
table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {padding:4px;vertical-align:middle;}
```

When I set the property to top there everything appears as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You're using tables, which is strongly discouraged, especially as of late, and you're not even using them correctly...

Your line breaks in the table data are expanding the row vertically. The vertically aligned middle table data (in this case the water and scandinavia bits) is being centered in a larger row than you would like. It would be better to change the structure of your footer, but with minimal changes, you could get away with changing the rowspan to the amount of line breaks inside of it.

Comment: I know CSS is recommended but I don't know how to do it with CSS. Thank you for the answer, I have an OK output now.

Answer (score -1):

I know a trick, play with `padding-top`.

Comment: That isn't so great if the user's browser is enforcing a larger than expected minimum font size, say the vision impaired or a mobile browser...