# How to vertically align text within a column with CSS columns?

Tags: css

Is it possible to vertically align text when using CSS columns? For example, if I wanted text within each column to be aligned to the top, center or bottom?

I've tried using vertical-align, but that doesn't seem to work on an unordered list or it's items:

**html**

```
<div class="nav-banner__list-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav-banner__list">
    <li class="nav-banner__list-item">Some Item</li>
    <li class="nav-banner__list-item">Some Item</li>
    <li class="nav-banner__list-item">Some Item</li>
    <li class="nav-banner__list-item">Some Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.nav-banner__list {
  vertical-align: center;
  column-count: 2;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.nav-banner__list-item {
  vertical-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Any code? Did you try anything else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align text in my columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051358/how-to-vertically-align-text-in-my-columns)

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper apologies, updated with code sample above.

Comment: @MarcB It looks like that solution deals with tables, rather than CSS columns. I tried using vertical-align, but that doesn't seem to work (unless I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: You can't. CSS columns are **not elements**, they are styles. You can't center something in a style.

Answer (score -2):

Use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` properties.